# Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to integrate AWS PHP SDK for codeigniter

But its showing error as follows

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Aws\Exception\CredentialsException

Message: Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials

Filename: /var/www/html/aws/Aws/Credentials/CredentialProvider.php
```

And on cli getting an error as
-bash: /root/.aws/credentials: Permission denied

So after this i have allowed permission ... cli error has gone but php error  Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials still remain.

Please help to solve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: what are the file permissions now and what user does CI app run on behalf of?

Comment: It looks like the application is running as root user and /root does not have `.aws`.

Comment: @titogeo for us path for aws is /home/ubuntu/.aws.

Comment: Is your PHP server running as root? if it is then you need `/root/.aws/credentials` not in `/home/ubuntu/.aws`

Comment: @titogeo for us path for aws is /home/ubuntu/.aws. We can successfully get result for command root@ip-****-**-**-**:~# aws configure list ... But when tried to execute command root@ip-****-**-**-**:~# ~/.aws/credentials  gives us an error as ===> /root/.aws/credentials: line 1: [default]: command not found
/root/.aws/credentials: line 2: aws_secret_access_key: command not found
/root/.aws/credentials: line 3: aws_access_key_id: command not found

Comment: @titogeo Our application running at /var/www/html/

Comment: That's the location. What is the user that is running your application?

Comment: How to check that ??

Comment: Where are you running this code? Locally on your machine, or inside AWS (e.g. EC2). That makes a difference regarding credentials.

Comment: @Olivier De Meulder we are running this code on ec2

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If your are using IAM Role to EC2 Instance then there is no need of using following

```
'profile'=>'default',
```

i just remove above line which solved error "Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials"

[Issue using an IAM role with PHP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919316/issue-using-an-iam-role-with-php-sdk?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

When running code on another AWS service, you do not work with key and secret, as you would on your local machine. Take a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52389947/1330328) I gave on another question.

Basically, your EC2 instance is assigned a service role. Then you would attach one or more IAM policies to that role. The IAM policies will determine what AWS resources and actions your EC2 instance can access.

In your PHP code you would instantiate your client using the `CredentialProvider::defaultProvider()`. If you were working with S3 for example, it would look like this.

```
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'region' =>'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => CredentialProvider::defaultProvider()
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

When PHP is running under a service there is no "user".  Therefore PHP will not attempt to access /root/.aws/credentials. If you review the error the path is /.aws/credentails.

To solve this problem create a new directory `/.aws` and copy the directory `/root/.aws` to `/.aws`

Improvement:

You have installed the PHP SDK inside your website root folder which makes these files accessible externally. SDKs should be installed outside of your website folders.

Comment: where to create /.aws directory

Comment: create the directory in the `/` directory. That is what `/.aws` means.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply..i am getting same error after following steps you have mentioned... Is there any thing else need to do ..??

Comment: This should be higher up!  Thanks, it worked like a charm (local development enviro).

Answer (score 1):

For me in the development environment i didn't use iam role so didn't need to access the `.aws/credentials` file.

By removing the `'profile'=>'default'` from the `$config` you tell the SDK not to look for `.aws/credentials` file, and then you can call the service construction with `key` and `secret`

When using`'profile'=>'default'`, the sdk will first look for the `.aws/credentials` file and if not exists will throw an exception

For example :

```
        $config = array(
            'region'  => $region,
            'version' => $version
        );

        $credentials = new Credentials($key, $secret);
        $config['credentials'] = $credentials;
        

        $dynamoDbClient = new DynamoDbClient($config);
```

Comment: This worked for me, I needed to remove the profile param, and pass my IAM credentials. Thanks!