# How is it possible to use the current EC2 instances IAM role in AWS ADK PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns, aws-php-sdk

I would like to use SNS/SQS in my PHP application, that is running on an EC2 instance.

I was able to find the guide about [credentials for the AWS SDK for PHP Version 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html), but I still have no idea how to simply use the IAM Role that is associated with my EC2 instance, my app is running on.

This is what I tried:

```
$SnSclient = new SnsClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'eu-central-1',
    'version' => '2010-03-31',
    'credentials' => \Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider::defaultProvider()
]);
```

But I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Cannot read credentials from /home/ec2-user/.aws/credentials in phar:///var/www/html/aws.phar/Aws/Credentials/CredentialProvider.php:874
```

I would like to avoid uploading my pem file to the instance, since it is already running in AWS, as far as I know it should be able to use it's IAM role

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary No, it gives the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'profile' => 'default',` line had to be removed, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31955322/3042117)

It does not seem to be well documented, but if you are using the IAM Role of the instance, then no `profile` or `credentials` attributes are necessary

Comment: It is well documented for every SDK, including PHP https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html#default-credential-chain

Comment: Please accept your answer to mark the question as answered.

Comment: @jordanm Unfortunately, it is not